# OSX 10.6 Sync with Google Contacts, Address Book or Itunes?

Tags: mac, itunes, sync, gmail, contacts

Should I use the sync functionality of Address Book or iTunes to sync Google Contacts? Pros and Cons?

Answer (score 0):

I sync my Google Contacts with my Android phone and my OS X address book. I haven't had any problems with it at all. It mostly works unattended and don't even have to think about it.

One disadvantage is that you never really know when it syncs the contacts (or I haven't found the setting yet), so if you're doing edits in Google Contacts it takes a while before they show up on your Mac.

(But what is the deal with iTunes?)

Comment: that's what i'm doing now, albeit with an iPhone. I am wondering if the iTunes sync would perform better than the Address Book Sync.